# Camel-SMPP support for SOURCE_HOST and and SOURCE_PORT

Tags: apache-camel, smpp, jsmpp

Does camel-smpp support setting a specific source host and port to create a `SocketConnection` towards the SMS-C?
According to my knowledge there are no URI parameters to set the `SOURCE_HOST` or `SOURCE_PORT`.

If there exist such parameters please point me to.
Otherwise, any suggestions for possible resolution?

Comment: Can you explain more what SOURCE_HOST and SOURCE_PORT is?

Comment: Hi Claus. What I want is to be able to bind my ESME(my app) to bind at a specific local IP and local port. I though these parameters were not available  in came-smpp component. After further investigation it is not feasible in JSMPP as well. `org.jsmpp.session.connection.socket` 
package is responsible for creating socket Connections to the SMS-C and it doesn't support `java.net.Socket(InetAddres remoteAddress, int remotePort, InnetAddress localAddres, int localPort)`

I am closing it. It doesn't have to do with Camel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an issue of Camel.
Underlying SMPP library (jsmpp) doesn't support creating a bind to a remote SMS-C by first binding in a specific local address and port.